# Calculate time duration between different events

Tags: r

I have a data set:

```
here_dat <- '
ID,Event,Date
1,Pre-trans,01-01-2018
1,Event1 start,09-01-2018
1,Trans,19-01-2018
1,Trans,09-01-2018
1,Event1 end,19-01-2018
1,Post-trans,20-01-2018
1,Event2 start,21-01-2018
1,Trans,22-01-2018
1,Trans,23-01-2018
2,Pre-trans,01-01-2018
2,Event1 start,07-01-2018
3,Pre-trans,01-01-2018
3,Event2 start,09-01-2018
3,Trans,11-01-2018
3,Trans,13-01-2018
3,Trans,14-01-2018
3,Trans,17-01-2018
3,Event2 end,19-01-2018
3,Event1 start,25-01-2018
3,Event1 end,27-02-2018
'
events <- read.table(text=here_dat, sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

1. There are two types of event: Event1 and Event2
2. Event1 start/end will not overlap with Event2 start/end
3. Events may not have end date

I want to calculate the time duration between each type of event for each ID. If an event doesn't have end date, then use the current date as end.

The ideal output:

```
ID Event.type Event.startDate Duration
1 Event1 09-01-2018 10
1 Event2 21-01-2018 138
2 Event1 07-01-2018 152
3 Event2 09-01-2018 10
3 Event1 25-01-2018 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse) 
events %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Date=as.Date(Date, format="%d-%m-%Y")) %>% 
  separate(Event, letters[1:2], sep=" ") %>% 
  filter(grepl("Event", a)) %>% 
  spread(b, Date) %>% 
  mutate(Duration=ifelse(is.na(end), Sys.Date() - start, end- start))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     ID a      end        start      Duration
  <int> <chr>  <date>     <date>        <dbl>
1     1 Event1 2018-01-19 2018-01-09       10
2     1 Event2 NA         2018-01-21      138
3     2 Event1 NA         2018-01-07      152
4     3 Event1 2018-02-27 2018-01-25       33
5     3 Event2 2018-01-19 2018-01-09       10
```

The idea is to spread start and end to easily substract both dates. Here we can use the `tidyverse` functions to transform the `Date` and `Event` colum. Then `separate` to `filter` for "Envents" and finally `spread`.